# How do candies fall in Candy Crush Saga?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

When I play Candy Crush Saga new candies usually fall into the board from the top of the board, but sometimes I notice they wall into the current column from the adjacent columns and not from the top of the board.

Knowing how candies fall are critical in later levels, especially in the combo candy order levels and ingredient levels with stuck zones.

What's the algorithm that govern how the candies fall? I can't find it described anywhere of web...

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely dependant on the level. Most levels as you've seen are simple top to bottom and follow the expected route (that gravity would provide). However some levels have different routes which the candy will follow once it is free to move.

Generally you won't know this until you start the level, which is a little annoying when you realise you've just screwed yourself out of an awesome move! However sometimes when you start the level you may get lucky when something entirely unexpected happens instead.